# Angular selector tag

Tags: angular, angular6

In the official ng-book (p. 73) I read that is possible indicate an Angular 6 component tag in 2 different ways. Example from the official manual:

1. `<inventory-app-root></inventory-app-root>`
2. `<div inventory-app-root></div>`

but in my Angular application only the 1st way works.

```
<app-test-component></app-test-component>
```

(work)

```
<div app-test-component></div>
```

(doesn't work)

Why is this?

Comment: As far as I could understand, you are confusing selector with directives. 
Check this out https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Not what happend, but in every case your link is very interesting and useful. Thank you too!

Comment: Welcome. Check it out. You might come up with more ideas for your solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your component code, there will be a decorator that looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
```

The `selector` property is what Angular will use to find your component. It's value can be any valid CSS selector, so by default, it expects a tag called `my-app`.

If you want to change it to an attribute, you can use:

```
selector: '[my-app]',
```

Comment: Not sure it's good practice though, the component should be a tag, not an attribute.

Comment: Exactly answer to my question, thank you very much, in the manual I haven't found this indication (or I will find later).

Comment: @Archimede There's more info [in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#component-metadata) if you're interested. If this has answered your question, can you please mark as accepted with the green tick? This will make it easier for others to find in the future should they need to.

Comment: Already done, but I read "impossible unless 3,2,1... minutes"! I only wait the end of countdown to mark your answer. :-) Thank!